# parseFloat() function

Tags: float, functions

I have noticed that the parseFloat() function returns decimal numbers, but only up to 2 decimal places. Would it be possible for it to return the numbers with more decimal places? In case we need more precision

Comment: how did you get to that conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the `parseFloat()` function returns decimal numbers

No, it doesn't. It returns a **binary** (not decimal) floating point
number.

> only up to 2 decimal places

The number returned by `parseFloat()` has 24 significant digits.
Binary digits, that is, also called “bits”. This is roughly equivalent
to 7 decimal digits.

That being said, beware of `Serial.print()`. This function converts
binary floating point numbers to decimal, and defaults to showing only
two digits after the radix point. You can ask for more:

```cpp
Serial.println(x, 6);  // display x with 6 digits after the radix point.
```

If you want to gain some basic understanding of how floating point
numbers work, I recommend reading [The Floating-Point Guide - What Every
Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very educational!